# Protractor Not Showing Stack Trace in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, jasmine, protractor

I am new to protractor and visual studio code so bare with me. I have already tried to look for solutions to this on stackoverflow and google but was not successful.

Basically I am running e2e tests through protractor inside visual studio code with a terminal command e.g. 'npm run e2e:local' which runs 'export ENVIRONMENT=local && protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js

The tests run fine and all except there is not any kind of stack trace upon failure, so I have no idea how/where to look for the error in my code.
Here is an example output of a test run:

````
[16:55:47] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Jasmine started

  Construction NZ Level 50 user
    ✗ Can create a project with all fields filled in and with a contractor
      - Failed: Invalid locator

**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) Construction NZ Level 50 user Can create a project with all fields filled in and with a contractor
  - Failed: Invalid locator

Executed 1 of 3 specs (1 FAILED) (2 SKIPPED) in 31 secs.
[16:56:22] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[16:56:22] I/launcher - chromeANY #01 failed 1 test(s)
[16:56:22] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[16:56:22] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! HazardCoHub@1.3.10 e2e:local: `export ENVIRONMENT=local && protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the HazardCoHub@1.3.10 e2e:local script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dmitrikoudrin/.npm/_logs/2020-08-27T04_56_22_187Z-debug.log```

So as you can see it just says "Failed: Invalid locator" which is of no help to me as it could be any one of a 100 locators in the code.
All I want is for it give a standard stack trace and point me to the function that's failing. It would be even better if it could print what locator it tried to find/use before failing.


Full log:
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/dmitrikoudrin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/dmitrikoudrin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'e2e:local' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'pree2e:local', 'e2e:local', 'poste2e:local' ]
5 info lifecycle HazardCoHub@1.3.11~pree2e:local: HazardCoHub@1.3.11
6 info lifecycle HazardCoHub@1.3.11~e2e:local: HazardCoHub@1.3.11
7 verbose lifecycle HazardCoHub@1.3.11~e2e:local: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle HazardCoHub@1.3.11~e2e:local: PATH: /Users/dmitrikoudrin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/dmitrikoudrin/hazardco_hub_2/node_modules/.bin:/Users/dmitrikoudrin/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/dmitrikoudrin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools:/Users/dmitrikoudrin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/dmitrikoudrin/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/dmitrikoudrin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools:/Users/dmitrikoudrin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin
9 verbose lifecycle HazardCoHub@1.3.11~e2e:local: CWD: /Users/dmitrikoudrin/hazardco_hub_2
10 silly lifecycle HazardCoHub@1.3.11~e2e:local: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'export ENVIRONMENT=local && protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle HazardCoHub@1.3.11~e2e:local: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle HazardCoHub@1.3.11~e2e:local: Failed to exec e2e:local script
13 verbose stack Error: HazardCoHub@1.3.11 e2e:local: `export ENVIRONMENT=local && protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/dmitrikoudrin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/dmitrikoudrin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid HazardCoHub@1.3.11
15 verbose cwd /Users/dmitrikoudrin/hazardco_hub_2
16 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/dmitrikoudrin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node" "/Users/dmitrikoudrin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/npm" "run" "e2e:local"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error HazardCoHub@1.3.11 e2e:local: `export ENVIRONMENT=local && protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the HazardCoHub@1.3.11 e2e:local script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
````

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you also post the contents of the complete run as provided in /Users/dmitrikoudrin/.npm/_logs/2020-08-27T04_56_22_187Z-debug.log?

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52734643/9150146

Comment: No it doesn't, as I already have that @Sergey

Comment: @AwSnap added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your config has

```
    jasmineNodeOpts: {

        // If true, display spec names.
        isVerbose: true,

        // If true, print colors to the terminal.
        showColors: true,

        // If true, include stack traces in failures.
        includeStackTrace: true,

    },
```

Comment: Which config are you talking about please? As there are a lot of config files... There's a protractor.conf.js, there's a tsconfig.json, there's protractor.conf-dev.js, there's config-local.json, there's launch.json, etc.

Comment: look up where `jasmineNodeOpts` is specified in protractor